# MasterViewController absent in Landscape

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

[image]

Hello everybody!
I've googled, read the documentation.. But...
 Does anyone has an idea WHY did it happen?

And the weirdest problem, me and my friend have similar ipads(iPad 3 4G (iOS 6.0.1)). And this is his screenshot. I cannot even reproduce it. We both have iOS 6.0.1.

Please, any idea/hint will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That looks like a split view controller inside a tabbed interface.  If so, that's not a supported configuration and you may get **any** kind of result.